# Is it possible to use HTTPS with OpenRasta?

Tags: security, rest, https, openrasta

Does anyone know if it is possible to use HTTPS with OpenRasta rather than plain HTTP? I need HTTPS so that sensitive information can be transferred without any risk..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from using openrasta with SSL, it's supported. You'll have to ensure that your host environment (asp.net I assume?) is configured properly for it.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if because it worked closer to the protocol than say an ASP.Net website, if I would have problems..